# Node js loop through JSON and get latest values per team based on the timestamp

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

i have the following Json object

```
 let my_array = 
  [
   {
    timestamp: '1571967208',
    team: 'team1',
    goals: '2'
   },
   {
   timestamp: '1571967150',
   team: 'team2',
   goals: '1'
  },
  {
  timestamp: '1571967110',
  team: 'team1',
  goals: '0'
  },
  {
   timestamp: '1571967067',
   team: 'team3',
   goals: '4'
  },
  {
   timestamp: '1571966896',
   team: 'team1',
   goals: '5'
  },
 ]
```

i want to get the latest from above Json per team based on the timestamp. for example if team 1 latest is goals 2 then new array should only have that likewise for other teams.

expected result like bellow

```
let my_array = 
  [
   {
    timestamp: '1571967150',
    team: 'team2',
    goals: '1'
   },
  {
   timestamp: '1571967067',
   team: 'team3',
   goals: '4'
   },
 {
  timestamp: '1571966896',
  team: 'team1',
  goals: '5'
  },
 ]
```

since the 5 goals is the latest for team 1 based on the timestamp

Comment: All you have to do is a simple `for` loop.  Track a "results" object of sorts.  If you haven't seen the team name yet, or if the timestamp is greater than the timestamp you've already stored, overwrite that object with the current one.

Comment: thanks it worked added my answer in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `lodash`, this can be very simple and readable

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const input = 
  [
   {
    timestamp: '1571967208',
    team: 'team1',
    goals: '2'
   },
   {
   timestamp: '1571967150',
   team: 'team2',
   goals: '1'
  },
  {
  timestamp: '1571967110',
  team: 'team1',
  goals: '0'
  },
  {
   timestamp: '1571967067',
   team: 'team3',
   goals: '4'
  },
  {
   timestamp: '1571966896',
   team: 'team1',
   goals: '5'
  }
 ];

const grouped = _.groupBy(input, "team");
const latestGoal = Object.keys(grouped).map(item => _.sortBy(grouped[item], ["timestamp"])[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Map` will be more efficient when array size will grow.

```js
const latestResults = new Map();
const my_array = 
  [
   {
    timestamp: '1571967208',
    team: 'team1',
    goals: '2'
   },
   {
   timestamp: '1571967150',
   team: 'team2',
   goals: '1'
  },
  {
  timestamp: '1571967110',
  team: 'team1',
  goals: '0'
  },
  {
   timestamp: '1571967067',
   team: 'team3',
   goals: '4'
  },
  {
   timestamp: '1571966896',
   team: 'team1',
   goals: '5'
  },
 ];

my_array.forEach(curObj => {
  const lastObj = latestResults.get(curObj.team);
  if (lastObj == null || Number(lastObj.timestamp) < Number(curObj.timestamp)) {
    latestResults.set(curObj.team, curObj);
  }
})

const resultsArray = [...latestResults].map(result => result[1]);
```

Result:

```js
[
  {
    "timestamp": "1571967208",
    "team": "team1",
    "goals": "2"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1571967150",
    "team": "team2",
    "goals": "1"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1571967067",
    "team": "team3",
    "goals": "4"
  }
]
```

Comment: this code will only get the latest result not per team. result should be latest score per team

Comment: @nicolewillson this will get latest per team... https://jsfiddle.net/96o58ubj/#&togetherjs=L5eCnVS3tb

Answer (score 0):

```
  let my_array_new = []

  my_array.forEach(function(entry) {

      addItem(entry);

  })


function addItem(item) {
   var index = my_array_new.findIndex(x => x.team== item.team && x.timestamp >= 
     item.timestamp)
     if (index === -1) {
     my_array_new.push(item);
     }else {
     console.log("object already exists")
     }
 }
```